# Angular $resource timeout config not returning an error

Tags: angularjs, connection-timeout

I'm trying to set a timeout limit of 10 seconds on a specific $resource request, but in all cases I'm getting a successful response, and am unable to test the error. I thought setting the timeout to 50 ms, or throttling my network speed via DevTools would let me produce the error for working with the response, but no luck. Is there something I'm failing to understand?

snippet from my service (MyService):

```
return $resource(`${url}/:id`, { id: '@_id' }, {
  query: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: true,
    timeout: 10000 // have tested with 50
  },
  ... additional actions ...
}
```

I'm making this $resource call from a ui-router resolve

snippet from a resolve in my route config (ui-router):

```
return MyService.query(paramsObj).$promise
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(data);

    // ...additional code removed...
    // return parsed data;
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  });
```

In all cases I'm seeing success logged in the console, but I don't understand why I can't produce a timeout error. From what I can tell I'm using it how it's documented in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try `.catch(response => {...})`

Comment: The timeout doesn't appear to have any effect on the request; I get a 200 when I expect it to timeout, so what you proposed wouldn't be triggered. Thank you though

Comment: I suggest you try it. There is a subtle yet important difference between 'catch' and the second argument to 'then'. The latter only gets invoked on server errors, while 'catch' gets invoked on both server and any other errors.

Comment: I did try as you suggested and unfortunately still wasn't able to catch it. I went through my various scenarios of network throttling, adjusting the timeout number, attempting to pile up test data in my dev env (tens of thousands of entries).. perhaps I need more data, but still feel what I have should have been sufficient for a low timeout limit.. thank you again.